# Selenium.Key Action with Java Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Java WebDriver most recent release firefoxbrowser is the only one I'm coding for. this is for automation not testing.

Disregarding the lack of headers and such.
I simply am attempting to select a text box.
then send a ctrl-home so that the cursor is placed at the beginning of the box.
then based on some previously identified criteria it is supposed to send the delete command x amount of times.  Well it selects the text box, and I can see the cursor flicker around, but it does not appear to be jumping to the top home position, and doesn't appear to be deleting anything.  Obviously my first concern is the home position.

```
int a = 0;
int del = dateline_name.length();
del = del + 2 ;                                 
                driver.findElement(By.id("id_story")).click();
                    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                    action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.HOME).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
                        while (a <= del)
                            {
                            action.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE).perform();
                            a++;
                            }
```

Comment: You're missing some important information. What version of Selenium? Does the issue manifest in all browsers? If not, which browsers and which browser versions?

Comment: firefox 17 stable / long

Answer (score 0):

You have miss build() call before doing perform().
Check below link

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fselenium.polteq.com%2Fen%2Fperform-a-sequence-of-actions-with-selenium-webdriver%2F&ei=LdgqUafxKMHqrAet-YDwDg&usg=AFQjCNFte5BvMd6HS4Nk7jEgc_r-206dlg&sig2=suBy4U--uTGp2JxHK5otWw

Comment: Good attempt, but `.perform()` does a `.build()` internally anyway. So I'd be surprised if that was the issue. (I'm not entirely sure what is the issue here).

Comment: I can see it place the cursor in the text box, and I can see the cursor "flicker" for a bit like its attempting to do something, its just not executing the command.

Comment: +1 to Arran's comment, .build() is definitely implicit and not required only .perform() is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same with Firefox and observed that if there is no keyUp(Keys.CONTROL) in the action, it works. Please try removing the keyUp from the action sequence. Thanks.

Comment: I have some interesting results now that I have debugging turned on. I will post them soon.

Comment: Sendkey's Key's. home will take it to the home position of the line its on.  the keydown for CONTROL  event with our without the keyUp event has no effect on the outcome. it simply will not go to the beginning of the textbox.